# SSIS C# script won't run with reference to Newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, ssis

We have an SSIS package that executes a Script Component in the Data Flow Task.  This script is in C# and it is referencing Newtonsoft.Json to connect to a website and get data from the website.  This package was originally created in SSDT 2010, was deployed to a SQL Server 2012 instance, and ran successfully.  We are in the process of migrating our SSIS packages to a new SQL Server 2017 instance and the package was upgraded to SSDT 2015.  Now the package throws an error when trying to execute the Script Component.  The error is:

Error: 0x1 at Get product meta, Error Getting Data From Webservice!: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
at ScriptMain.GetWebServiceResult(String wUrl)
at ScriptMain.parsejson(String uri, Boolean& hasmore)

We've been Googling the error with very little success or understanding of the issue.  Has anyone had this issue before and, if so, does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Comment: You need to get the assembly into the GAC. SSIS script tasks don't know how to repull from nuget once the editor session closes

Comment: Did you modify th connection string to refernce new SQL Server?

Comment: How do I add the assembly to the GAC?  Sorry for the stupid questions, but this is way more C# than it is SSIS and I'm not a .NET developer.